# Correct User's Inputted URL - Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have a url input box, but I'm thinking I'm going to change it because users still don't always enter in the url correctly as shown in an example and the url still allows a few variations. I was wondering how I could turn a user entered url into the format I want. Say I want the following format in the end:

```
http://www.example.com/
```

but the user enters in one of the following

```
www.example.com
www.example.com/
http://www.example.com
```

The other way would be if they didn't use a subdomain so the end result needs to be:

```
http://example.com
```

and they type in either:

```
example.com
example.com/
http://example.com
```

The code I need should be able to handle correctly formatting any formatting mistakes to get it into the desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def correct(url, protocol='http')
  url = url.sub(%r{^https?://}, '')
  protocol = $& || "#{protocol}://"
  #url = url.chomp('/') + '/'  # Uncomment to ensure the url to ends with `/`
  url = 'www.' + url unless url.start_with? 'www.'
  protocol + url
end

correct('www.example.com')        # "http://www.example.com"
correct('www.example.com/')       # "http://www.example.com/"
correct('http://www.example.com') # "http://www.example.com"
correct('example.com')            # "http://www.example.com"
correct(' example.com/')          # "http://www. example.com/"
correct('http://example.com')     # "http://www.example.com"
correct('https://example.com')    # "https://www.example.com"
```

Comment: this breaks https-urls

Comment: @levinalex, You're right. I updated the code to respect the protocol (default to `http`). Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and my solution in `Rails`

in `application_helper.rb`:

```
def address(link)
  return link if link.scan(/(https:\/\/)|(http:\/\/)/).any?
  link.split('').unshift('http://').join('')
end
```

in `views`:

```
= link_to "", address(user.website)
```

in `pry`:

```
=> helper.address("http://www.example.com/")
=> "http://www.example.com/"
=> helper.address("example.com")
=> "http://example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the [domainatrix](https://github.com/pauldix/domainatrix) gem:

```
require 'domainatrix'

str = 'example.com'
url = Domainatrix.parse(str).url  #=> "http://example.com"
```